# Could you please explain the detail of the proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, self-learning

Proposition:[image]
Proof:
[image]

Question:
Why it's isomorphism?

Comment: It's the difference between $\frac as+S^{-1}\mathfrak p$ and $\frac{a+\mathfrak p}s$, roughly speaking. You should be able to come up with an isomorphism along these lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a homomorphism $f: S^{-1} A \rightarrow \bar{S}^{-1} (A/p)$ by sending $a/s$ to $\bar{a}/\bar{s}$ where $\bar{a}$ denotes the class of $a$ modulo $p$. Then show that this homomorphism is surjective and that its kernel is precisely $S^{-1} p$.